# How to update div A after div B has been swapped

Tags: javascript, html, htmx

I'm trying to figure out how to make this HTML structure work with htmx

```
<div id="optionscontainer" hx-get="http://localhost:8000/get_optionsview" hx-trigger="load"
  hx-swap="innerHTML" class="mb-5">
</div>
<div id="logincontainer" ...>
</div>
```

Every time the `#logincontainer` is updated, I'd like to also refresh the `#optionscontainer`. I think the right way would be to subscribe to events, here's the code I'm using:

```
document.body.addEventListener('htmx:afterSwap', function (event) {
  if (event.target.id === 'logincontainer') {
    // this log message appears as expected
    console.log("should reload options now");
    // this query selector works as expected
    let optionsContainer = document.querySelector("#optionscontainer");
    console.log(optionsContainer);

    // this doesn't seem to do anything
    htmx.trigger("#optionscontainer", "htmx:refresh");
  }
});
```

For some reason, the `htmx.trigger` doesn't have any effect. I've gone through various event names such as `reload`, `refresh`, etc.

Apart from that I think my routes work. Here's how the website behaves:

1. load website. There is a GET to the options route on the first page load, but then the options are supposed to still be absent, cause the user is not logged in. The placeholder is displayed correctly. So the GET to the options route is working. Click "login", the "login" button is swapped out for "logout". This also causes a bearer token to be set. Which I can see in the dev tools. The options are not reloaded.
2. reload page. It's still the "logout" button, the bearer token is of course still set. Now I see the correct options (reloading has sent a new GET request to the server). Click "logout". The button is swapped for "login", the bearer token is deleted. The options are not refreshed, no new GET request.
3. jump back to step 1.

I'm also aware of the two other solutions that could be applicable here:

- restructure the DOM layout, have the options be a child of the login container. But that would mess with separation of concerns on my server. I'd like to keep those routes separate. If I have the options template included in the login/logout template, then I need to fill in the options in that route.
- OOB swap. That would allow me to keep the HTML on the client the same. But on the server I'd similarly have to deal with filling both the auth and options template in the same route.

Answer (score 1):

You may consider using custom triggers as documented [here](https://htmx.org/attributes/hx-trigger/#triggering-via-the-hx-trigger-header).

In your scenario the beckend response from `logincontainer` needs to include the custom `hx-trigger` header.

```
HX-Trigger: my-custom-event
```

And then inform `optionscontainer` to handle this extra event, like so:

```
hx-trigger="load, my-custom-event from:body"
```

Comment: thank you, this works. Would it also be possible to refresh the optionscontainer via an event that I trigger from Javascript?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, but I think as long as you use htmx to trigger the event, it should work the same from javascript eg. `htmx.trigger("body", "my-custom-event");`